# Listing numbered files using wildcard sequence with predefined range

Tags: bash, ls, filenames, wildcards, seq

I have a folder of numbered data files. I am trying to incrementally extract a predefined range of files. The range of files that I am looking for is predefined in two variables, ns and ne, which change as the code runs.

I have been attempting something like the following:

```
$ ns=0001
$ ne=0030

$ ls foo_{$ns..$ne}.nc
```

But this does not read `{$ns..$ne}` as a sequence, and returns the error:

```
ls: cannot access foo_{0001..0030}.nc: No such file or directory
```

If I type the same command, but with the numbers entered manually, I get a list of files with numbers ranging from 0001 to 0030 as expected.

I presume that I am making a fundamental error in the use of sequencing, but would appreciate someone informing me what this error is.

Many thanks.

Comment: The problem is that brace expansion happens before parameter expansion, so you can't use variables in the brace expansion.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion

Comment: `eval "echo foo{$ns..$ne}"` but uh you really want to use `seq` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brace expansion happens before variable expansion, so there's no way to use variables in it. You can use `seq` instead:

```
seq -f foo_%03.0f.nc $ns $ne
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `{1..20}` is not a wildcard/globbing operator. That's a special form of brace-expansion introduced by `zsh` and copied with limitations and variations by `ksh93` and `bash`.

`foo_{0001..0030}.nc` doesn't expand to the list of matching files, it expands to `foo_0001.nc`, `foo_0002.nc`, ... `foo_0030.nc` regardless of whether the files exist or not.

`bash` has that limitation that the content cannot be variable. `ksh93` and `zsh` don't have that limitation.

So `ls -d foo_{$ns..$ne}.nc` will work in those shells.

`zsh` also has a globbing/wildcard operator to match decimal number ranges.

```
ls -d foo_<1-30>.nc
```

Will expand to the list of matching files. If you want to limit it to 4 digit 0-padded ones, you'd need another operator:

```
ls -d foo_(<1-30>~^????).nc # needs extendedglob
```

(`~` is *except* (*and-not*), `^` is *not*, so `~^` is *and-not-not*, so *and*).

The `<x-y>` operator doesn't work with variables though (because it overlaps with redirection operators, it only works when following the `<[digits]-[digits]>` pattern to avoid clashes with redirections as much as possible). You can however use this syntax to work around it:

```
ls -d ${~:-foo_<$ns-$ne>.nc}
```

Or more legibly:

```
pattern="foo_<$ns-$ne>.nc"
ls -d $~pattern
```