# Loop in macOS not working

Tags: shell-script, shell, osx, brace-expansion

I need to execute the following shell script in my macOS terminal.
The loop never executes more than its first iteration.

```
function execute_function() {
# Launch job
  number_of_jobs=$1
  echo "Launching ${number_of_jobs} jobs"
  for i in {1..$1}; do
    job_id=`head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Z0-9 | head -c 6 ; echo ''`
    echo "Launching Job: $job_id"
    echo $i
  done
}
```

When I run it, I always get:

```
execute_function 10

    Launching 10 jobs
    Launching Job: XX9BWC
    {1..10}
```

The same happens if I replace: `$1` with `$number_of_jobs` or `"${number_of_jobs}"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is variable in braces expansion.

Try rewriting it to

```
for ((i=1;i<=$1;i++))
do
  #your code here
done
```

Comment: That worked perfectly

Answer (score 9):

Your script is written for `zsh` but you are executing it with `bash`.

`bash` does not support using variables as ranges in brace-expansions.

To resolve this, simply arrange for the script or function be executed in a `zsh` shell (especially if the script is longer than what you are showing and is using other `zsh` features).  This shell is installed by default on macOS as `/bin/zsh`.  You may add `#!/bin/zsh` as the first line in the script to have it execute with `zsh` by default.

See also:

- [Listing numbered files using wildcard sequence with predefined range](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285184/listing-numbered-files-using-wildcard-sequence-with-predefined-range)
- [How can I use $variable in a shell brace expansion of a sequence?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-variable-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence)
- [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script)

Comment: include `#!/bin/zsh` as first line. (you may need to check the path.

Comment: what about `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`?

Comment: @JakubJindra That would work to, but the default location of `zsh` _is_ `/bin/zsh` on macOS.  Obviously, you may want to use `env` if you need to use a 3rd-party installation of `zsh`.  However, this is not the essence of this particular question.